# managing relative urls in static html files for django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a static directory which contains bunch of html files and images. All html files contain links to each other using relative paths. For instance, a page describing an algorithm has a link such as `<a href ../../newmethod/algo2.html>Algorithm 2</a>`. Everything in this directory works very well in a portable manner in any static server.

I want to use django to add a page banner to each html file under this directory. Is there anyway to achieve this using a template which contains the banner code and includes the static htmls file using an "ssi" directive?

The problem that I cannot find a solution is the relative paths in the static htmls. When I include the static html in the template with ssi, the relative paths (such as the image paths in the html file), become completely wrong. For instance an image with `<img src='../images/flow.bmp>` in the static html does not point to correct address of the image any more.

Is there anyway to correct this relative url problem in django?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in accessing the files in a static environment as compared to the web server is that the directory root and web server root file systems are likely to be different. You can adjust your relative paths for that.

Besides as a framework django expects html templates to reside inside `templates` either within your app or at the `project/templates/app/` level. Static assets like images should be managed as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). User uploaded media should be handled as [media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MEDIA_ROOT)

Then in your templates use `{{STATIC_URL}}` or `{{MEDIA_URL}}` wherever appropriate.

So in that case your `../../newmethod/algo2.html` should be in the directory accessed from the one where the current template is via 'cd ../../newmethod' within the `templates` directory

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add an HTML `<base>` element in to change what all the links refer to:

```
<base href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ request.path }}"/>
```

This will mean that the browser interprets the links as though the file had been served from `/static/path/to/file.html` instead of `/path/to/file.html`. I found that this made linking the other static html files more complicated, though, since they were then linked to directly.

Instead, you can just serve a redirect for other URLs so that they get registered in position relative to the HTML that's being served through a template (in my case, I want all html files in `/static/projects` and below to be served through a `projects_frame.html` template). In `urls.py`:

```
# Handle projects by serving static files in a frame; redirect indexes
url("^projects/(?P<path>[^./]+)/$", RedirectView.as_view(url="/projects/%(path)s/index.html")),
url("^projects/[^/]+/.*[.]html$", direct_to_template, {"template": "projects_frame.html", "extra_context": {"STATIC_FILES_ROOT": settings.STATIC_FILES_ROOT}}, name="projects"),
url("^projects/(?P<path>[^/]+/.*[.].*)$", RedirectView.as_view(url="/static/projects/%(path)s")),
```

My template then looks like this (I'm using mezzanine so this is not universally applicable, but should give an idea):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n staticfiles %}

{% block meta_title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb_menu %}
<li class="active">{% trans "Home" %}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% ssi STATIC_FILES_ROOT|add:request.path %}
{% endblock %}
```

PS `STATIC_FILES_ROOT` is a custom variable I defined because of a problem I encountered with `STATIC_ROOT`